# Converting daily data in a CSV to monthly averages via R?

Tags: r, csv, average, data-conversion

I have daily data in a spreadsheet, which in R I have named "df". The data is in the simplified format of two columns, X1 and X2.

X1 is the daily date in the format 01/01/1990... etc

X2 is just a numerical value

What I'd like to do is convert these daily values into monthly averages.

Previously I was given the following code to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- mutate(df, X1 = dmy(X1),Year = year(X1), Month = month(X1))
df <- group_by(df, Month, Year)
df <- summarise(df, result = mean(X2) )
```

However, now when I'm putting this code in, I'm receiving the error

```
50: In mean.default(structure(c(336L, 220L, 187L, 175L, 193L,  ... :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

The problem seems to be with the final line of code;

```
df <- summarise(df, result = mean(X2) )
```

Could anyone please advise how this code might be fixed? I'm not sure why it has now ceased to work. Alternatively if there is another method to find monthly averages, it would be most welcome.

Comment: Which `01` is the month in `01/01/1990`? Also: don't name anything `df`in `R`. It's already the name of a buildin function and while naming values like functions works pretty well, it can lead to misleading error messages in case of syntax errors.

Comment: Please put the result of `str(df)` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data looks something like this:

```
fakedata = data.frame(X1 = c("01/01/1990", "01/02/1991", "02/01/1990"),
                  X2 = c(1, 2, 99), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

that is

```
> str(fakedata)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X1: chr  "01/01/1990" "01/02/1991" "02/01/1990"
 $ X2: num  1 2 99
```

and that the first `01` in `01/01/1990`denotes the month, you can do without any extra packages like e. g.

```
fakedata$months = unlist(Map(function(x) strsplit(x, split="/")[[1]][1], fakedata$X1))
aggregate(fakedata$X2, by=list(fakedata$months), FUN=mean)
```

Also: don't name anything `df` in `R`. It's already the name of a buildin function and while naming values like functions works pretty well, it can lead to misleading error messages in case of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

With data.table and xts, it's coming relatively easy : (see @Bernhard' dataframe)

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)
dtf <- data.table(fakedata)
dtf[, X1 := as.Date(X1)]
xts <- as.xts.data.table(dtf)
z <- aggregate(xts, format(index(xts),"%m"), function(d) c(mean(d)))
z
```

gives

```
01 50
02  2
```